# Command "schedule:list" is not defined. Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, scheduler, laravel-6

Working on a laravel 6 project. But when I try to execute `php artisan schedule:work`, it shows

> "Command "schedule:list" is not defined".

`php artisan schedule:list` shows the same error. Only `php artisan schedule:run` is working. But scheduler is not executing command as scheduled. It works only when I execute `php artisan schedule:run`

Answer (score 2):

`schedule:work` was introduced in Laravel 7, so it's not available in Laravel 6.

Comment: but why isn't scheduler not working as scheduled. It works only when I execute 'php artisan schedule:run'

Comment: run ```php artisan ``` to see all artisan commands that are available in your laravel version.